# How is async with await different from a synchronous call?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I was reading about asynchronous function calls on [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443(v=vs.140)).

At the first example, they do this, which I get:

```
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

// You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
DoIndependentWork();

string urlContents = await getStringTask;
```

But then they explain that if there's not any work to be done in the mean time, you can just do it like this:

```
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();
```

From what I understand, the `await` keyword will suspend the code flow until the function returns. So how is this different from the synchronous call below?

```
string urlContents = client.GetString();
```

Comment: It doesn't block the main execution context/thread, so e.g. UI won't be frozen (in an application that uses the UI).

Comment: But this is mainly because the method itself is `async`, right? Won't that mean that as long as it's busy with stuff, the calling thread can continue?

Comment: No, async is needed so it can call await. All the magic happends on the await call.

Comment: Ah, so if the method calls a 'regular' slow function, it will still block the main thread?

Comment: when you write Await then all the lines after the call in that function will not execute until async function execution completes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Calling `await client.GetStringAsync()` yields the execution to the calling method, which means it won't wait for the method to finish executing, and thus won't block the thread. Once it's done executing in the background, the method will continue from where it stopped.

If you just call `client.GetString()`, the thread's execution won't continue until this method finished executing, which will block the thread and may cause the UI to become unresponsive.

Example:

```
public void MainFunc()
{
    InnerFunc();
    Console.WriteLine("InnerFunc finished");
}

public async Task InnerFunc()
{
    // This causes InnerFunc to return execution to MainFunc,
    // which will display "InnerFunc finished" immediately.
    string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();

    // Do stuff with urlContents
}

public void InnerFunc()
{
    // "InnerFunc finished" will only be displayed when InnerFunc returns,
    // which may take a while since GetString is a costly call.
    string urlContents = client.GetString();

    // Do stuff with urlContents
}
```

Comment: I finally got it when I read "The difference between synchronous and asynchronous behavior is, a synchronous method returns when its work is complete, but an async method _returns a task value when its work is suspended_.". So asynchronous function will still behave like synchronous functions, *until* they issue an `await` statement, which will return control to the caller.

Comment: @Rijk: An asynchronous function is not necessarily marked with `async` identifier - and not necessarily issue an `await`. A normal function returning a `Task` or `Task<T>` can be considered as asynchronous function and you can `await` on it.

Comment: @Adi Lester: Isn't the first `InnerFunc` (the one with the `await` in its body) definition missing an `async` in its signature? Also, shouldn't it return a Task?

Comment: @PedroMachado you are correct. Edited my answer

Comment: @AdiLester, thanks. I was waiting for that to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 16):

> From what I understand, the await keyword will suspend the code flow until the function returns

Well, Yes and No.

- Yes, because code flow does stop in a sense.
- No, because the thread executing this code flow does not block. (The synchronous call `client.GetString()` will block the thread).

In fact, it will return to its calling method. To understand what it means by return to its calling method, you can read about another C# compiler magic - the `yield return` statement.

Iterator blocks with `yield return` will break the method into a state machine - where code after the `yield return` statement will execute only after `MoveNext()` is called on the enumerator. (See [this](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) and [this](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx)).

Now, `async/await` mechanism is also based on similar state machine (however, its much more  complicated than the `yield return` state machine).

To simplify matters, lets consider a simple async method:

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    // code block 1 - code before await

    // await stateement
    var r = await SomeAwaitableMethodAsync();

    // code block 2 - code after await
}
```

- When you mark a method with `async` identifier you tell the compiler to break the method into a state machine and that you are going to `await` inside this method.
- Lets say code is running on a thread `Thread1` and your code calls this `MyMethodAsync()`. Then `code block 1` will synchronously run on the same thread.
- `SomeAwaitableMethodAsync()` will also be called synchronously - but lets say that method starts a new asynchronous operation and returns a `Task`.
- This is when `await` comes into picture. It will return the code flow back to its caller and the thread `Thread1` is free to run callers code. What happens then in calling method depends on whether calling method `await`s on `MyMethodAsync()` or does something else - but important thing is `Thread1` is not blocked.
- Now rest of await's magic - When the Task returned by `SomeAwaitableMethodAsync()` eventually completes, the `code block 2` is *Scheduled* to run.
- `async/await` is built on the Task parallel library - so, this *Scheduling* is done over TPL.
- Now the thing is that this `code block 2` may not be scheduled over the same thread `Thread1` unless it had an active `SynchronizationContext` with thread affinity (like WPF/WinForms UI thread). `await` is `SynchronizationContext` aware, so, `code block 2` is scheduled over same `SynchronizationContext`, if any, when the `MyMethodAsync()` was called. If there was no active `SynchronizationContext`, then with all possibility, `code block 2` will run over some different thread.

Lastly, I will say that since `async/await` is based on state machine created by compiler, like `yield return`, it shares some of the shortcomings - for example, you cannot `await` inside a `finally` block.

I hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: I would like to leave a comment here that starting C# 6, one can `await` in `finally` block.

Comment: In which thread is `SomeAwaitableMethodAsync()` run?

Comment: @PedroMachado - `SomeAwaitableMethodAsync()` method will be called over `Thread1`, however, whether it will complete over same thread or not will depend on it's implementation, and/or whether it itself is also a `async/await` state machine.