# Ensure that children functions have terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function that walks recursively over a folder, performing an expensive operation on each file. So far, the function was simple and pretty:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
async function openPath(path) {
    // Path is a directory
    if (fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()) {
        let subPaths = fs.readdirSync(path);
        for (const file of subPaths) await openPath(path + '/' + file);
    // Path is a file
    } else await expensiveOperationWithDB(path);
}
```

Realizing that I only needed file processing to be synchronized when the files were on the same directory, I came up with this ugly function:

```js
async openPath(path, isFile) {
        if (isFile) await expensiveOperationWithDB(path);
        else {
            const subPaths = fs.readdirSync(path);
            for (let newPath of subPaths) {
                newPath = path + '/' + newPath;
                if (fs.statSync(path).isFile()) {
                    await this.openPath(newPath, true);
                } else {
                    this.openPath(newPath, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the function should return only when its children functions have terminated. How can this be implemented?

Comment: I don't see any code that starts new processes? Also, if you're using async/await, rather than `readdirSync`, import from [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) instead of plain fs, and then you can `await fs.readdir`, `await fs.stat`, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess it is my bad English. Instead of processes, I mean children functions. As to await fs.readdir, etc., yes, I could use that. Isn't it the same?

Comment: processes (i.e. child_process.spawn and child_process.exec) are very specific things: if you're not spawning new threads or processes, don't call them that: you're going to confuse people =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Got it, won't happen again. As for the other question, I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250047/how-is-async-w-await-different-from-a-synchronous-call#:~:text=I%20finally%20got%20it%20when,its%20work%20is%20suspended.%22.).  You can tell I'm new to async functions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to collect all the promises from any called functions into an array and use `Promise.all` on them.

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
async function openPath(path) {
    const stat = await fs.stat(path);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        return openDirectory(path);
    } else if (stat.isFile()) {
        return expensiveOperationWithDB(path);
    }
}
async function processDirectoryFiles(filePaths) {
    for (const path of filePaths) {
        await expensiveOperationWithDB(path);
    }
}
async function openDirectory(path) {
    const names = await fs.readdir(path);
    const pathStats = await Promise.all(names.map(name => {
        const newPath = path + '/' + file;
        const stat = await fs.stat(newPath);
        return {
            path: newPath,
            isFile: stat.isFile(),
            isDirectory: stat.isDirectory();
        };
    }
    const promises = [];
    const filePaths = [];
    for (const {path, isDirectory, isFile} of pathStats) {
        if (isDirectory) {
            promises.push(openDirectory(path));
        } else if (isFile) {
            filePaths.push(path);
        }
    }
    promises.push(processDirectoryFiles(filePaths));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved. I still have a doubt, though. Is there a need to check for both `isDirectory` and `isPath`? Couldn't you just use an `else` without any conditions on it? (Like I did in the question)

Comment: @LoremIpsum Probably not, in most use cases. But see [the `Stats` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsstats) for which other kinds of file system objects there are - you probably don't want to process them. So I thought it's better to check and be safe :-)